# Using R, how to create Winning percentage using a column of data

Tags: r

I have a column of numeric values and would like to convert this into a Winning percentage.

Winning percentage is defined like this:

```
Winning percentage = (Wins+0.5*Ties)/Total Values
```

1. Calculate values that are higher, lower and equal in the list
2. Divide by total number of values in the list.

So given a list of values:

```
106.32 
92.56
96.35
29.54
92.56
93.32
```

Win Pcts are:

```
1.000
0.417
0.833
0.000
0.417
0.667
```

This is as close as I got:

```
(length(which(dataframe[1,1] > dataframe[1]))/length(dataframe[,1]))
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. See [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2359523) with how to improve your question, namely by providing an example dataset. Also, I may not completely understand, if you could clarify. What are you trying to calculate in 1? Isn't that just your total games? Or is that a score column?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(season13)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(season13, 20))`.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what a win is in your formula?